# GDAL Warp giving garbage data on edges when transforming to WGS 84

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I want to change one tiff file to USGS DEM file. For that I am doing following steps:

1. Transform the tiff file to WGS84 coordiantes using Gdal Wrap utility

   gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata -90909 -of GTiff Source.tif DestWGS84.tif
2. Then convert the WgS84 tiff file to DEM file using Gdal Translate utility

   gdalTranslate -of USGSDEM DestWGS84.tif Final.dem

When I pass -dstnodata swirch in gdalwarp uitlity the created DEM file have invalid data at the edges. 
    [image]

But when I don't pass the no data switch then the minimum elevation is not set (shows zero) and hence other computaion fails.
[image]

Can we create DEM file without transforming it in WGS84??

Answer (score 2):

Provide the source DEM no data value as well in the command line.

Try the following command:

gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata {source no data value} -dstnodata -90909 -of GTiff Source.tif DestWGS84.tif

This should help in fixing the zero elevation issue you have.